# Error using Zebra MX extensions AppManager

Tags: xamarin.android, motorola-emdk

I'm trying to use Zebra Mx extensions App Manager on Xamarin with the EMDK package.
My device is a Zebra TC51 with Android 7.1

When I'm calling the function :

```
string[] modifyData = new string[2];
modifyData[0] = ProfileManager.CreateNameValuePair("AppMgrInstall", "Action", "Install");
modifyData[1] = ProfileManager.CreateNameValuePair("AppMgrInstall", "APK", "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackage/files/apks/install.apk");
EMDKResults results = arg.ProcessProfileAsync("AppMgrProfile", ProfileManager.PROFILE_FLAG.Set, modifyData);
```

The result is :

> The processing of profile started, the result will be returned through the data listener callback registered

but the data listener is never called.

If I use the synchronous method `ProcessProfile()`, the app gets stuck indefinitely on the line.

When I look in logcat what happens on the device, I have this error that pops up :

> AppList_AllowedSubmitXml
>   ERROR: Unable to load static file

What can be the cause of the error?

How could I find more information related to this error?

I searched AppList_AllowedSubmitXml on Google search engine but it returned 0 results.

EDIT:
Here is my EMDKConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--This is an auto generated document. Changes to this document may cause incorrect behavior.-->
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="ProfileInfo">
        <parm name="created_wizard_version" value="7.3.2"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="Profile">
        <parm name="ProfileName" value="AppMgrProfile"/>
        <parm name="ModifiedDate" value="2020-01-09 09:19:51"/>
        <parm name="TargetSystemVersion" value="8.0"/>
        <characteristic type="AppMgr" version="8.0">
            <parm name="emdk_name" value="AppMgrInstall"/>
            <parm name="Action" value="Install"/>
            <parm name="APK" value="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackage/files/apks/install.apk"/>
        </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the ProcessProfile API in that way, your project needs to have a corresponding EMDKConfig.xml file and modifyData() can only be used to modify the contents of that file prior to submission, if needed.

It may be easiest to copy the WiFi sample from https://github.com/Zebra/samples-emdkforxamarin-4_0/tree/samples-emdkforxamarin-5_0/ProfileWifiSample1.  That sample can enable / disable the WiFi amongst other tasks and you can modify the project XML to suit your needs using the EMDK for Xamarin Visual Studio extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EmdkForXamarin.EMDKforXamarin-19166) .  The VS Extension gives you a visual editor, I would not recommend trying to modify the XML directly.

I notice that the WiFiSample always modifies the XML in code before processing but this is not required - an example of an app that does not modify the xml before sending is https://github.com/darryncampbell/DevTalk-Securing-Your-Zebra-Device/blob/master/SecurityManagers/SecurityManagers/MainActivity.cs#L293

Update (see comments): The following code will install a specified apk:

```cs
string[] modifyData = new string[1];
modifyData[0] = "<? xml version =\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
modifyData[0] +=  "<characteristic type = \"Profile\" >";  
modifyData[0] +=   "<parm name = \"ProfileName\" value = \"AppMgrProfile\" />";
modifyData[0] +=   "<parm name = \"ModifiedDate\" value = \"2020-01-10 13:14:07\" />";
modifyData[0] +=   "<parm name = \"TargetSystemVersion\" value = \"7.0\" />";
modifyData[0] +=   "<characteristic type = \"AppMgr\" version = \"7.0\" >";
modifyData[0] +=     "<parm name = \"emdk_name\" value = \"AppMgr\" />";
modifyData[0] +=     "<parm name = \"Action\" value = \"Install\" />";
modifyData[0] +=     "<parm name = \"APK\" value = \"/storage/emulated/0/install.apk\" />";
modifyData[0] +=   "</characteristic>";
modifyData[0] += "</characteristic>";
EMDKResults results = arg.ProcessProfileAsync("AppMgrProfile", ProfileManager.PROFILE_FLAG.Set, modifyData);
```

Comment: I have an EMDKConfig.xml, written with EMDK Profile Manager Extension in Visual Studio 2019. I managed to use the Power Manager App to reboot the device that way

Comment: Has the device been previously staged in any way? (E.g. by invoking the MX Access manager)? Can you link to a sample app with the issue?

Comment: The device hasn't been staged afaik. Projet published on github : https://github.com/phkraus/ChuAppsXamarin_appmanager thanks

Comment: Thanks for the github repo, I have updated the above answer with a code snippet that works for me.  Also, I think you will need to store your apk in a world readable location (you currently have it in your application sandbox)

Comment: It does work, even though it takes 5 minutes to install the apk (5mb, MyOrange.be) and it returns an error "error in installing apk" but the app is correctly installed.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @DarrynCampbell. I have a question. Do I have always an EMDKConfig.xml file in my asset to execute an mx script? I try to explain. For example, I have an EMDKConfig.xml with a string that reboot the device... Can I use ProcessProfileAsync PROFILE_FLAG.Set to execute an mx script to install an apk (or do I have this script inside the EMDKConfig.xml before i "set" it...)

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro you would typically have two different profiles defined in your EMDKConfig.xml to achieve that, one to do the reboot and the other one to install the app.  But yes, you DO need an EMDKConfig.xml file in your asset folder

Comment: Sorry @darryncampbell.. On the emdkconfig I have only the reboot. The install arrive from a webservice. Can I execute it?